# Bitwise subtraction

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitmask

Given the enum:

```
[Flags]
enum foo
{
a = 1,
b = 2,
c = 4
}
```

then

```
foo example = a | b;
```

If I don't know if foo contains `c`, previously I have been writing the following

```
if (example & foo.c == foo.c)
    example  = example ^ foo.c;
```

Is there a way to do this without checking for the existance of `foo.c` in `example`?

As when it comes to additions, I can just do an **`OR`**, and if the enum value already exists in `example` then it doesnt matter.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you want:

```
example &= ~foo.c;
```

In other words, perform a bitwise "AND" mask with every bit set *except* the one for `c`.

EDIT: I should add an "except" to [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) at some point, so you could write:

```
example = example.Except(foo.c);
```

Let me know if this would be of interest to you, and I'll see what I can do over the weekend...

Answer (score 9):

AND it with the complement of foo.c:

```
example = example & ~foo.c
```